# Объясните, как работает этот foreach для tuple

Tags: c++, foreach, tuple

Помогите разобраться, как работает функция обхода кортежа:

```
template <typename F, typename T, size_t... i>
void tupleForeachImpl(F&& f, T&& t, std::index_sequence<i...>)
{
    auto unused = { true, (f(std::get<i>(std::forward<T>(t))), void(), true)... };
}

template <typename F, typename T>
void tupleForeach(F&& f, T&& t)
{
    tupleForeachImpl(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<T>(t),
                     std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<std::remove_reference_t<T> >::value>());
}
```

Не могу понять, что за магия происходит в 4ой строчке(где unused).
Код увидел в коментариях к статье https://habrahabr.ru/post/318236/

Comment: Не пойму к чему ссылка приведена. У Вас есть проблема - описываете ее и что вы уже сделали для ее решения. Рекламировать чей то сайт/пост - не есть корректно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`unused` представляет собой фиктивный массив, при инициализации (начиная со второй позиции, чтобы оно работало для `tuple<>`) элементов которого будет исполняться выражение `(f(std::get<i>(std::forward<T>(t))), void(), true)...`. Это выражение разворачивается для каждого элемента кортежа. Теперь хитрая часть: внутри скобок сначала происходит вызов функции для i-того элемента кортежа c с заменой `i` последовательно на `0, 1, 2...`; затем к результату вызова функции применяется встроенный `operator ,`; на случай, если функция возвращает тип с перегруженным `operator ,` после запятой идет `void()`; затем идет еще один встроенный `operator ,` и, наконец, значение для инициализации массива - `true`.